# How to make Android application from from C++ program using OpenCV

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I have a C++ program that starts like this:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "linefinder.h"

#define PI 3.1415926

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int houghVote = 200;
    string arg = argv[1];
    bool showSteps = argv[2];

    string window_name = "Processed Video";
    namedWindow(window_name, CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO); //resizable window;
    VideoCapture capture(arg);
```

I want to make an Android app from it.
I have NDK installed but I don't know what I have to do now.

Do I have to change anything in the C++ main program so that it will run on Android, or can I compile and run it unchanged?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html

Comment: Yes, I already check that page, but it doesn't help. I have programs as face detection running, but I don't know how to do use my own C++ code into Android program

Answer (score 1):

[Introduction to Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)

> Android provides a rich application framework that allows you to build innovative apps and games for mobile devices in a **Java language environment**. ... Android apps are built as a combination of distinct components that can be invoked individually.

You need to construct your app using Java, then call your C++ code via JNI.

Also, [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Installing) has this to say

> you should only use the NDK if it is essential to your app—never because you simply prefer to program in C/C++

In particular, read [Using the NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Using) to understand why *you can't run your C++ main program without changing anything*.